# What is the best bucket size for a task queue filled with many deferred tasks in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, task-queue, deferred-execution

My Google App Engine application is adding a large number of [deferred tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Deferred_Tasks) to a [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview). The tasks are scheduled to run every x seconds. If I understand the bucket-size property **b** correctly, a high value would prevent the deferred tasks to run until **b** tasks have been added. However, there is a close-to-realtime requirement that the tasks run as scheduled. I do not want that the tasks are blocked until the **bucket-size** is reached. Instead they should run as close to their scheduled time as possible.

To support this use case, should I use a **bucket-size** of 1 and a **rate** of 500 ([which is the current maximum rate](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues))? Which other approaches exist to support this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The bucket size does not prevent tasks from running individually. It plays a different role.

Suppose you have an empty queue with rate of 500 tasks per second, and several hours where no tasks are added or started. Then suddenly a large number of tasks are added at once. How many of these tasks would you like started immediately?  Set this number as your bucket size. For example, with a bucket size of 1000, 1000 tasks will be started immediately (then 500 per second going forward).

How does this work? The bucket is topped up by 500 tokens every second (the queue's rate), up to the maximum being the bucket size. When there are tasks are available to start, they will only be started while the bucket is not empty, and one token will be removed from the bucket as each task is started.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use taskqueues (TQ) for deferred tasks that are important to run close-to-realtime using the assumption that bucket/rate setting will assure high throughput. There have been several discussion threads in Google groups about infrequent delays with task start times that are minutes or more in length. Bucket size and rates will not have an affect on this -- your TQ tasks will simply sit there while your high-throughput TQ is idle. To date I have not ever seen any explanation from Google as to why this occurs. Again, if you utilize TQs for close-to-real-time tasks you MUST handle as an exception the infrequent times when your tasks will delay for minutes prior to starting. (I in fact do this, and have not yet been negatively affected, but you have to have code in place to handle a result = delayed task). My great hope is that with the new server/application testing underway, Google will find an easy way to kill this incredibly big issue with TQs (fingers crossed).

Comment: Can you elaborate how would you "...have code in place to handle a result = delayed task"?